# How do I only wrap some pages in a Context Provider with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-context

I have three pages that I want to share data between (these are the core of the web app) but I also have a bunch of blog pages that don't care about that data. Everywhere I've looked suggests putting the Provider in the `_app.tsx` file. If I understand that correctly if I wrapp `MyApp` with the provider, if someone goes straight to [www.myurl.com/blog/my-blog-1](http://www.myurl.com/blog/my-blog-1) (from google), that will cause the provider to run its functions; even if that page won't call useContext

How do I only wrap three pages in the Provider and leave out the blog pages?

For example:

- [www.myurl.com](http://www.myurl.com) -> I want this to use the shared data from the provider
- [www.myurl.com/my-functionality](http://www.myurl.com/my-functionality) -> I want this to use the shared data from the provider
- [www.myurl.com/profile->](http://www.myurl.com/profile-%3E) I want this to use the shared data from the provider
- [www.myurl.com/blog/](http://www.myurl.com/blog/)* -> I don't want this to call the functions in the auth provider

Here's what my `_app.tsx` looks like:

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import '../styles/index.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 11):

A bit late to the party but there is actually an official way to do this:
Use a [per page layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts).
First slightly tweak your `_app.tsx` file:

```
import type { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
    getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
    Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};
export const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout): unknown => {

    // Use the custom layout defined at the page level, if available
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);

    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />);
};
```

Then in a Page component write the following:

```
// DashboardPage.ts that need to have a UserProvider and CompanyProvider
import Layout from '@components/Layout'; // Default Layout that is imported for all the page
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { UserProvider } from '@contexts/user';
import { CompanyProvider } from '@contexts/company';

const DashboardPage = (): JSX.Element => {
    return <DashboardContainer />;
};

// Custom Layout to wrap the page within the User and company providers
DashboardPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
    return (
        <Layout title="Dashboard page">
            <UserProvider>
                <CompanyProvider>{page}</CompanyProvider>
            </UserProvider>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default DashboardPage;
```

Comment: Hi, does this really preserve context values between pages? E.g. when you logged in, you have user in your `UserProvider` and you navigate to other page that's using the same layout, I doubt the user will stay in the context, will it?

Comment: For anyone encountering this, this works!

I have a multipage Formik form that only a subdirectory of my app is concerned with. The <Formik> tag which manages the Context is in the wrapping component that my layout uses.

I confirmed that when I navigate between pages using this layout, the context is preserved. 


As the docs say: `This layout pattern enables state persistence because the React component tree is maintained between page transitions. With the component tree, React can understand which elements have changed to preserve state.`

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is an interesting issue.

Challenge is in the way Next implements file-based routing. Since there is no way to create a wrapper for the group of pages only out-of-the-box thing you can do is to wrap the App in the context providers. But that doesn't really resolve your issue.

SOOO... I think there is a workaround. If you want to be able to wrap a certain group of pages in the context provider, first, you need to replace the file-based router with the react-router.

There is a very interesting article on this topic by Andrea Carraro. I think you should try this out:
https://dev.to/toomuchdesign/next-js-react-router-2kl8

I will try to find another solution as well, but let me know did this worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and for helping me think about this. I was hoping to keep the file-based router since it's one of the things I really like about Next.js. I ended up just adding the minimal amount of auth info in context and not sharing as much as I initially intended.

Answer (score 1):

There is workaround to wrap components of a specific path with a wrapper without react-router.
Check out this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69-mnojSa0M

The video shows you how to wrap components of a sub-path with a nested layout. Create a nested layout and wrap that that layout with your Context Provider.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind new to Next.js and looking for the same question.
Maybe we can just use `pathname` and `query` from the `useRouter` hook and try some conditionals in our `Contexts` or in the custom `_app`

[next/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter)

Answer (score 0):

Very late to answer my question, but my approach might help someone in the future.
I used a page as a wrapper, and to navigate around I used query params.

---

For example

- [www.something.com/blog](http://www.something.com/blog)
- wwww.somethiing.com/blog?id=1
- [www.something.come/blog?profileid=2](http://www.something.come/blog?profileid=2)

Answer (score 0):

I use contextProvider and check the path pages in _app.js

> myContextProvider.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const Context = React.createContext({});

export function myContextProvider({ children }) {
     const [ state1, setState1 ] = useState(true);

     return <Context.Provider value={{ state1, setState1 }}>
          {children} 
     </Context.Provider>;
}

export default Context;
```

> _app.js

```
import { useRouter } from 'youreFavoRouter';
import { myContextProvider } from './myContextProvider.js';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    
    const isBlogPage = router.pathname.includes('blog');

    return (
        <div>
            {isBlogPage ? (
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            ) : (
                <myContextProvider>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </myContextProvider>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now all states and function on myContextProvider can see and use on pages than you choose.
I hope help anyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I thought  I should post this somewhat of a solution I found that works for me so far. I thought maybe I could import my context in to one of my pages and test if wrapping a provider around with this would work. I am also new to Nextjs and don't know if this is a sound way of doing so, but it seems to work for me. I can access all my provided stuff from this component userprofile thats within my [username].tsx page.

Disclaimer Ive only done this for testing purposes

```
   // pages/[username].tsx
   import { UserProfile } from '@component/app/userprofile';


   const UserPage = () => {
   const router = useRouter();
   const { username } = router.query;

   useEffect(() => {
    
   console.log('Username:', username);
    }, [username]);

   return (
     <SampleContextProviderComponent>
       {user && user.map((user, index) => {
          if(username === user.username){

          return <UserProfile key={index} user={user}/>
          }
        })}
  
     </SampleContextProviderComponent>
     );
    };

    export default UserPage;
```